# How to find the soapAction with JQuery

Tags: jquery

can somebody help me with JQuery?

I want to find the soapAction of the element with the operation name Login in the following xml (I tried already with the method find but I didn't have success):

```
<wsdl:definitions name="AuthenticationService" targetNamespace="urn:zeitag.ch.tms.authenticationservice:v1" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="urn:zeitag.ch.tms.authenticationservice:v1" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:zeitag.ch.tms.authenticationservice:v1/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8833/TimeManagementService/Services/AuthenticationService/?xsd=xsd0" namespace="urn:zeitag.ch.tms.authenticationservice:v1"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8833/TimeManagementService/Services/AuthenticationService/?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8833/TimeManagementService/Services/AuthenticationService/?xsd=xsd2" namespace="urn:zeitag.ch.tms.entities.authenticationservice:v1"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8833/TimeManagementService/Services/AuthenticationService/?xsd=xsd3" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Ch.ZeitAg.Tms.TimeManagementService.Interface.ServiceEntities.AuthenticationService"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8833/TimeManagementService/Services/AuthenticationService/?xsd=xsd4" namespace="urn:zeitag.ch.tms.entities.common:v1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="AuthenticationService_GetServiceVersion_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetServiceVersion"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="AuthenticationService_GetServiceVersion_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetServiceVersionResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="AuthenticationService_Login_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Login"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="AuthenticationService_Login_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:LoginResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="AuthenticationService_Logout_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Logout"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="AuthenticationService_Logout_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:LogoutResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="AuthenticationService_TouchSession_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:TouchSession"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="AuthenticationService_TouchSession_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:TouchSessionResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="AuthenticationService">
<wsdl:operation name="GetServiceVersion">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="urn:zeitag.ch.tms.authenticationservice:v1/AuthenticationService/GetServiceVersion" message="tns:AuthenticationService_GetServiceVersion_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="urn:zeitag.ch.tms.authenticationservice:v1/AuthenticationService/GetServiceVersionResponse" message="tns:AuthenticationService_GetServiceVersion_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Login">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="urn:zeitag.ch.tms.authenticationservice:v1/AuthenticationService/Login" message="tns:AuthenticationService_Login_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="urn:zeitag.ch.tms.authenticationservice:v1/AuthenticationService/LoginResponse" message="tns:AuthenticationService_Login_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Logout">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="urn:zeitag.ch.tms.authenticationservice:v1/AuthenticationService/Logout" message="tns:AuthenticationService_Logout_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="urn:zeitag.ch.tms.authenticationservice:v1/AuthenticationService/LogoutResponse" message="tns:AuthenticationService_Logout_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="TouchSession">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="urn:zeitag.ch.tms.authenticationservice:v1/AuthenticationService/TouchSession" message="tns:AuthenticationService_TouchSession_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="urn:zeitag.ch.tms.authenticationservice:v1/AuthenticationService/TouchSessionResponse" message="tns:AuthenticationService_TouchSession_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationService" type="tns:AuthenticationService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetServiceVersion">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:zeitag.ch.tms.authenticationservice:v1/AuthenticationService/GetServiceVersion" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Login">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:zeitag.ch.tms.authenticationservice:v1/AuthenticationService/Login" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Logout">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:zeitag.ch.tms.authenticationservice:v1/AuthenticationService/Logout" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="TouchSession">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:zeitag.ch.tms.authenticationservice:v1/AuthenticationService/TouchSession" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="AuthenticationService">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_AuthenticationService">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8833/TimeManagementService/Services/AuthenticationService/"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Kind regards
Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use find with namespace:

```
$(xml).find("soap\\:operation[soapAction]")
```

Please check the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/3A23V/

**UPDATE1:**
For check on specific Action:

```
$(xml).find("soap\\:operation[soapAction*='Login']")
```

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/3A23V/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It's almost what I need :) Is there a possibility to get exactly soapAction of Login?

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: Yes, it's possible, I Updated the answer, please check

Comment: Hi Simon, thank you so much! At the moment I'm trying to get the targetNamespace attribute of the wsdl:definitions element.. But somehow it doesn't work..
I try it with the following statement: $(xml).find("wsdl|definitions").attr("targetNamespace")

What do I wrong?

Comment: just use $(xml).attr("targetNamespace") as it's the root element

Comment: Strange... It works on jsfiddle but not on my local machine.. Any advice?

Comment: That sounds strange, what is your jQuery version then? Maybe try to upgrade it

Comment: The code it's absolutely the same.. I copied yours from jsfiddle. However... Thank you for your support..

Comment: I mean the full code context, such as the 'xml' variable, I don't think you defined it from a string as I do, it should be something else right?

Comment: The code looks like that:

var ns = $(array_wsdl[i]).attr("targetNamespace");

In the array_wsdl there are some wsdl-definitions.. This call works:

var soapaction = $(array_wsdl[i]).find("soap\\:operation[soapAction*='" + method + "']").attr("soapAction");